# Message Queue: mgrcv doesnt print the mtext

Tags: c, linux, process, message-queue

I have a program that consists on 2 types of process, Worker and User. The Worker process will read from a named pipe, CONSOLE_PIPE, and then sends a message to a Message Queue. The User process will send information to the Worker Process on the named pipe CONSOLE_PIPE and then will wait and print the information that will be readed from the Message Queue. (**Both Process are in different files, I execute them in distinct terminals**)

I use a struct for the messages in the message queue.

```
typedef struct msgbuf {
    long mtype;      
    char mtext[200];
    alert msg_alert;
}msgbuf;
```

Here is the code part that sends a message to the message queue

```
//Message Sending
        if ((msgsnd(mqid, &message, sizeof(struct msgbuf), 0)) < 0) {

            fprintf(stderr, "msgsnd error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
            exit(1);
        } else {

            printf("Worker [%d] Sending message to Message Queue : %s \n",
                   getpid(), message.mtext);

        }
```

Here is the code parts that sends a message to the message queue

```
//Message received
if (msgrcv(msgid, &msg, sizeof(msgbuf), 1, 0) >= 0) {
                 printf("Received message: %s\n", msg.mtext);

             } else {
                 printf("msgrcv result: error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
             }
```

The problem is that when the User Process tries to print the mtext it prints nothing, but if I make it to print mtype it prints that value.

Other thing I tried, I setup the same message queue receive and printing function in the Worker code file and it worked fine.

Please if you have any questions about my problem that I did not make clear feel free to ask! (I also can send the full code to further testing, I made a version that do the functions I said above but in there worked fine).

Thanks for the time!

Comment: Aside: Cast the return of `getpid()` to an `int` in the call to `printf()`. There is no format specifier for a `pid_t`.

Comment: @Haris, then why would you assume it fits in an `int`?! It would be best to cast it to a `long long int` and use `%lld`.

Comment: @ikegami Because OP was using `%d`. I suggest `intmax_t` and `%jd`.

Comment: @Haris, It's rather ludicrous to assume `pid_t` fits in an `int` because the OP was using `%d`. // Indeed, `intmax_t` is a new one for me, and definitely even better.

Comment: Note that `msgsz` parameter is the size of the _payload_. Your `msgsz` args should be `sizeof(msgbuf) - sizeof(long)`. Otherwise, you have UB because you go 4/8 bytes _beyond_ the end of your buffer

Comment: We really need to see some more code. If the `msgrcv` returns non-negative, then we want to see what `message.mtext` is set to by the sender. AFAICT, that's the only way you'd get an empty message on the receiver (e.g. `mtext[0] == 0`). Otherwise, I assume that the sender does: `message.mtype = 1;` before doing `msgsnd` [or receiver would just hang].